# Beachballing during “NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];”

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My app (seemingly in debug mode only), *sometimes* (in seemingly unpredictable ways) beachballs infinitely during this simple statement:

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
```

It just beachballs infinitely. Nothing is happening. The memory usage is not changing at all. It could be that the app is hitting an infinite loop somewhere within the frameworks.

What could possibly be causing this? How could I analyze the cause?

Comment: I would restart, that is not normal, it sounds like the windowing manager is jacked up. if it still happens try it on some other hardware and see if it still does it

Comment: @JustinMeiners Well it’s not like it is just happening now. It’s been a random issue for a while now (during which I’ve restarted and shut down many times). Usually, on second or third try it starts working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to how to analyze it:  When you say "debug mode", do you mean it's running under the debugger?  If so, what happens if you hit the Pause button?

Another possibility is to use Activity Monitor to take a sample of your process while it's beachballing.

Comment: Yeah, I mean when it’s running under the debugger. I’ll try your suggestions and get back to you when this happens again. When that will be, who knows :S

Comment: Are you sure it's not stopped at a breakpoint? Also, you're using `NSOpenPanel` only on the main thread, right?

Comment: @KenThomases I’m pretty sure I wasn’t stopped at a breakpoint. However, I don’t remember 100%. I’ll make sure to check that out too next time this happens. I’ll also make sure I’m on the main thread (which I should be). Thanks!

Comment: @KenThomases Well, of course I can just set a breakpoint myself at that line to see whether it’s executing on the main thread. I just did, and I found out that it’s indeed running on the main thread. Phew :) I’ll keep you all updated about further results if and when this issue occurs again.